# Requests/actions on mobile applications cannot be recorded in Jmeter via HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

Tags: android, mobile, jmeter, performance-testing, proxy-server

I want to do performance test on a mobile app so that I am using Jmeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. I followed the belows steps before testing:

1. Open Jmeter
2. Select Templates > Recording and Create a recorder
3. I have everything I need like Test Plan > Thread Group > Recording
   Controller or Workbench > HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder > View
   Results Tree and so on
4. In HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder I set a port
5. Then I press "Start" button and a pop-up is appeared that states
   **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt** is created under .\bin directory
6. I go to .\bin directory and installed the certificate
7. Then, I used my mobile device (in this case, Google Nexus 10) to
   install **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt**
8. I send the file to myself and follow this path: Settings > Wifi >
   Advanced > Install Certificates
9. I installed the certificate and see a message like "Network may be
   monitored" which means installation is ok.
10. Then modify the network I use; set Proxy option as Manual, set host
     IP as the same one with my laptop which I run Jmeter and set the
     port number same in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and I saved the changes
11. Finally, I open some apps or using Chrome but nothing can be seen in Jmeter

PS: My laptop and the device are in the same network

- I tried to use some filter for URL patters but nothing change.
- I reviewed the open tickets related to this issue but I could not find an answer
- I can successfully record changes that I do in Firefox or Chrome in
  my laptop but for mobile case I cannot

Also, I checked the jmeter.log file, however; I could not see any error

I guess, there is a simple configuration problem but I could not figure out

Lastly,
Jmeter version: 3.3
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Android: 5.1.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You might need a third-party application like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) in order to be able to route all the traffic to JMeter's proxy. Other settings look good, so your setup should work fine.

You can also try an alternative way of recording a JMeter test on mobile device - it is [cloud-based proxy](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-) which automates certificate installation process. As a little bonus it can export recorded scripts in SmartJMX format with automatic detection and correlation of any dynamic parameters so you will be able to save some time on adding and configuring the relevant PostProcessors.

Comment: Hi, I tried ProxyDroid and it did not work out, however; by blaze meter I recorded requests on tablet. I will try another third party application like ProxyDroid. Thank you for advices.